# GetLastError() = 2

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port

I am new with using serial port in C++. I have found many examples for this purpose, one of them is in
[Configuring a Communications Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

However, I already almost get error number 2 which means ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND according to [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I cannot figure it out. I am using visual C++ 2010 Express. No doubts, the problem arose from OPEN_EXISTING command :

```
TCHAR *pcCommPort = TEXT("COM1"); //  Most systems have a COM1 port
hCom = CreateFile( pcCommPort,
                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                  0,      //  must be opened with exclusive-access
                  NULL,   //  default security attributes
                  OPEN_EXISTING, //  must use OPEN_EXISTING
                  0,      //  not overlapped I/O
                  NULL ); //  hTemplate must be NULL for comm devices
```

But why and what's the sulotion ?

Comment: If you don't have any hardware solution (real COM port or USB emulation), try this software emulation: http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

Comment: special thanks but I got one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   //  Most systems have a COM1 port
```

That was 20 years ago.  Motherboard manufacturers stopped putting COM ports on the board well over a decade ago, USB just completely replaced it as the dominant and superior way to talk to devices.

You'd only ever a COM1 port in the machine if you purchased an PCI board with true serial ports.  The far more common scenario today is a BlueTooth or USB driver that *emulates* a serial port.  There are no real standards for the way their drivers work, but they typically start numbering the emulated ports at COM3 or COM5.  You also should give the native device name for such ports to avoid trouble with the driver not emulating the DOS namespace name for the port.  Use `"\\\\.\\COM3"` for example.

Use Control Panel + Device Manager to find the correct port number.

Comment: Actually know it, and the correct COM port was exactly COM1 but the problem was with the name as you said. tanx!

Comment: and another interesting thing is that the document I mentioned, was build in 2013 !

Comment: It is stunning how fundamentally broken these drivers are.  Adding the DOS namespace name is completely trivial.  The cut-throat hardware business just doesn't leave any money to pay a programmer a decent wage, I guess.